# How do VPNs block DNS queries to other interfaces?

Tags: vpn, dhcp, internal-dns

I'm trying to understand how DNS routing works with/without a vpn. I have the following interface.

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.1
```

nslookup on this works:

```
nslookup google.com 192.168.40.1
Address:  192.168.40.1
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
```

If I have a VPN running, I get another interface and dns queries get routed to this by default.

```
Unknown adapter Mullvad:
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.1
```

however if I now try to query DNS on the other interface it doesn't go through.

```
nslookup google.com 192.168.40.1
DNS request timed out.
```

but I can make requests to my local servers no problem.

```
curl 192.168.40.22:8080
OK
```

How does this work? ip traffic goes through but DNS is blocked? I understand VPNs normally setup route table rules to direct traffic to their gateway. But that is for ip correct? DNS shouldn't be affected by it. What's the underlying mechanism behind this? Is there a way I can force DNS queries on the other interface?

This is on windows, but my guess is it would work similarly on linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified answer:

Depending on how it's configured, the VPN client forces all traffic through a virtual interface, *i.e.,*  It blocks traffic on the local LAN. Since there's no local traffic, the client can use different name servers when the tunnel is active.

Answer (score 0):

I miss an **ipconfig** out on both scenarios, anyway, it sounds that without VPN you got IP and default Name Servers from local DCHPd, so your machine can request DSN resolution to the local Name Server.

After connecting to VPN, sounds that you got another IP from the VPN server and set the default route to the VPN interface, which means all traffic is going through the VPN, which probably can't reach your local Name Server.

To solve this you can use a global DNS Server (like 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1) that can be reached from both networks.